# Meteor.js hidden input on form gets blank when populating with same value

Tags: meteor

I had this in a template called "todo_form":

```
<input type="hidden" id="priority" value="{{todo.priority}}">
```

I then had a "rendered" callback setup on the form to read the value from that hidden input, and setup a jQuery UI slider with it.  The form was populated by clicking on a todo from a list (via a registered session var, "active_todo").

So, if I were to click a todo with priority of 10, and then click any other todo with the same priority `$('#priority').val()` would return blank... It worked fine as long as I clicked on a todo with a different priority.  I verified this by using the console - this field is getting set to blank!

My solution was to instead check for the registered "active_todo" and pull the priority from it, but I also had to update the hidden input: `$("#priority").val(active_todo.priority)`.

Anybody got any ideas?  here's the original (non working) rendered callback:

```
Template.todo_form.rendered = ->
    priority = $( "#priority" ).val();
    $( "#priority-slider" ).slider(
        range: "min"
        value: priority
        min: 1
        max: 10
        orientation: 'vertical'
        slide: ( event, ui ) ->
            $( "#priority" ).val( ui.value)
    )
```

And here is how I "fixed" it:

```
Template.todo_form.rendered = ->
    active_todo = Session.get('active_todo');
    $("#priority-slider" ).slider(
        range: "min"
        value: active_todo.priority
        min: 1
        max: 10
        orientation: 'vertical'
        slide: ( event, ui ) ->
            $("#priority").val( ui.value)
    )
    $("#priority").val(active_todo.priority) # SHOULDN'T HAVE TO DO THIS!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to understand what you're trying to accomplish, but I believe you simply want to have a slider whose value shows the priority of the selected ToDo item, and then you want to make it possible to change this value with the slider.

If so, that hidden input really isn't necessary. All you really need is to make the "current todo" a reactive data source. And you already have that with your "active_todo" Session variable. Here's what I would suggest, in JavaScript (this is completely on-the-fly and untested):

```
var prioComp;

Template.todo_form.rendered = function() {
  $("#priority-slider").slider({
    range: 'min',
    value: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 10
    start: function() { 
      prioComp.stop();
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {  
      Session.get('active_todo').priority = ui.value;
      trackPriority();
    }
  });
  trackPriority();
};

function trackPriority () {
  prioComp = Deps.autorun(function() {
    $("#priority-slider").slider('value', Session.get('active_todo').priority);
  });    
}
```

Like I said, untested, so maybe a bug or two in here, but at least look at the code and try to understand what I'm attempting.

Comment: and yes, I'm leaving the Coffeescript translation up to you ;)

Comment: Won't this change the value of the priority in the collection as well?  I have my form setup to be an independent set of the data, so you can reset/cancel without having to reload the data from the db.  Is there a better way to do that?  I love your solution though, it's very elegant and shows the power of being reactive... it also reminded me i can set a property from Session.get()... I keep saving to a local var, updating its properties, and then calling Session.set()!

Comment: oh, when you wrote "todo from a list", I assumed you meant an array, not a collection. One thing you could do is save a copy of your ToDo documents in an array, using the _CollectionCursor_.fetch() method. And, assuming you're using an {{#each}} Handlebars loop to display the todos, you could pass the documents in your array to the {{#each}} instead of a Collection Cursor (i.e. instead of a Collection.find()). Then, when the user presses the **Ok** button on your form, you update the collection documents to match the ones in your array.

Comment: Again, brilliant answer.  And, yet again, I've failed to give you all of the information... =)  The list and the form are on the screen at the same time, side by side... I don't want the list changing while the form is being changed... but I like the fetch idea, does it have any other implications, perhaps on reactivity?  IE, if a user edits the same todo on another screen, will it still update on other screens? (in the app i'm building, projects can be shared or flat out public.)

Comment: your site is awesome btw =)

Comment: thanks! =) When you create a Collection Cursor, you can specify non-reactivity in your _options_ object, e.g. **myCollection.find({}, {reactive: false});** . See [this documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#find) for more info on that. But keep in mind that using a reactive data source only causes **reactive computations** to re-run. That's all explained [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity)

Comment: As for your app, well it sounds like you'll want your list view when users are _not_ editing priorities to reflect the current state of the collection. Your form's **Cancel** button, meanwhile, should do nothing but make the list once again reflect the the collection. You don't want to undo any changes that may have been done by other users while you were on the form. And changes to the collection are spread to all users once they've been done on the server's database

Comment: excellent explanation, makes good sense.  Thanks for the input! =)